# Insert to dict multiple keys from list with for loop in one line - dict.setdefault

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I tried to do this:

```
ip_dict = dict()
ip_list = ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
ip_dict.dict.setdefault(i for i in ip_list, 0)
```

And I get this exception:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

Can I do that in one line, or I have to do it in two lines?

Comment: `i for i in ip_list` is the same as `ip_list`. Next error now.

Comment: I know what it does, I just gave a simple example to here

Comment: @Python set default doesn't take a generator as an argument, this creates a dict which has a generator as one of it's keys and the value is 0

Comment: Mr python, if your problem is solved and you choose an answer as helpful, you can vote them up, however in order for you and the ansewrer to recieve reputation you should click the check mark in the answer you choose. I have seen lots of people wasting reputation for themselves and others by not checking answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can squish a for loop with a one-line body into one line:

```
ip_dict = dict()
ip_list = ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
for i in ip_list: ip_dict.setdefault(i, 0)
```

but if you really want the effect of exactly that code, [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) is all that’s needed:

```
ip_list = ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
ip_dict = dict.fromkeys(ip_list, 0)
```

Comment: @Python: Don’t actually use the first one… if your dict isn’t empty and that’s why you need `setdefault`, just put the loop on two lines. Being on one line makes it harder to read for no benefit.

Comment: I want to do it on none empty dict. And ok, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
ip_list = ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
ip_dict = {k:0 for k in ip_list}
```

and for a more complete example, if you have a list of default values

```
ip_list = ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
ip_default = [0, 1]
ip_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(ip_list, ip_default)}
```